# Read contents of a text file into a varchar WITHOUT using BULK

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulk

I've got a problem whereby I need to read data from a .txt file into a variable in SQL Server. The read needs to be performed programmatically, as it's going to form part of a stored procedure, and it needs not to utilise the BULK method, as I don't have permissions to use the BULK method on the database in question. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It's a lot easier with application code such as .net, java, coldfusion, etc.  Is this option available to you?

Comment: There are some details in this link: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/reading-and-writing-files-in-sql-server-using-t-sql/ around how to read data from a file in SQL-server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you get them to allow Ad Hoc Distributed Queries? Then you can use [OpenRowset or OpenDatasource](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179856.aspx).

```
SELECT * 
FROM   OPENROWSET('MSDASQL',  
'Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};DefaultDir=c:\users\graham\desktop;', 
'SELECT * FROM [data.txt];'
```

Here's the recofiguring code, if you need it:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
EXEC sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
go
```

This is a laborious technique, though -- you sure you can't use client code? Even, I dunno, VBA in Excel or something?

g.

Comment: It is indeed cumbersome, and I _could_ use code, sure. My problem is that it'll ultimately be other people that use the stored procedure that this forms part of; people who are most comfortable with SQL.

Comment: OK, then -- you need ad-hoc permissions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way to read the contents of a file without these permissions in SQL Server, or without setting up a link to the file. Otherwise, you have to do this through SSIS or using programming.

The solution is to get the permissions to solve your issue.