# Querying a .txt file on a web server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

The [National Weather Service's Climate Prediction Center](http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/) maintains data of recent weather data from about 1400 weather stations across the United States. The data for the previous day can always be found at the following address:

http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/analysis_monitoring/cdus/prcp_temp_tables/dly_glob1.txt

In an ambitious attempt to store weather data for future reference, I want to store this data by row using SQL Server 2012. Five years ago a similar question was asked, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5791946/5203406) mentioned the `BULK INSERT` command. I do not have access to this option.

Is there an option which allows for direct import of a web hosted text file which does not use the `BULK` statement? I do not want to save the file as I plan on automating this process and having it run daily direct to the server.

Update: I have found another option in [Ad Hoc Distributed Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19230606/5203406). This option is also unavailable to me based on the nature of the databases in question.

Comment: What is the preventing you from saving it to a temporary location, doing the bulk load, and then deleting it?  Is this a self-imposed restriction or is there some legitimate architectural impediment?

Comment: It is two-fold. I was looking to keep the entire processed contained in queries/subqueries, and I do not have access to the `BULK` command, even with local .txt files.

Comment: Have you considered using [SSIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms141026.aspx) in combination with a [SQL Agent job](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190268.aspx)?

Comment: Consider `insert... select ... from openrowset(bulk...)`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175915.aspx I would recommend to use xml format file with it.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you NOT have access to Bulk Insert?  I can't think of a reason that would be disabled on your version of SQL Server.

I can think of a couple ways of doing the work.

**#1)  Record a macro, using excel, to do everything from the data import, to the parsing of the data sets, and then to saving as a CSV file.  I just did it; very easy.  Then, use BULK INSERT to get the data from the CSV to SQL Server.**

**#2)  Record a macro, using excel, to do everything from the data import, to the parsing of the data sets.  Then use a VBA script to send the data to SQL Server.  You will find several ideas from the link below.**

http://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-sql-server-import-export-using-vba.htm#Excel%20Data%20Export%20to%20SQL%20Server%20using%20ADO

**#3)  You could actually use Python or R to get the data from the web.  Both have excellent HTML parsing packages.  Then, as mentioned in point #1 above, save the data as a CSV (using Python or R) and BULK INSERT into SQL Server.**

R is probably a bit off topic here, but still a viable option.  I just did it to test my idea and everything is done in just two lines of code!!  How efficient is that!!

```
X <- read.csv(url("http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/analysis_monitoring/cdus/prcp_temp_tables/dly_glob1.txt"))
write.csv(X, file = "C:\\Users\\rshuell001\\Desktop\\foo.csv")
```

Comment: The lack of `BULK` is a server permission based restriction. If I were to pass the issue on to someone with more permissions, then it would probably be the method used. That being said, all three are good options, but #2 really stands out as a potential answer to the question asked. There is still the issue of automating Excel to open and run the VBA code, but it's feasible.